# Positive completions of contractive linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let us assume that we have a contractive linear map $\Phi$ on the $3 \times 3$ (real) matrices; i.e. $\|\Phi(A)\| \leq \|A\|$ for any $A,$ where the norm is the operator norm (the largest singular value). Is there any counterexample which shows the $\Phi$ has no identity preserver, positive linear extension to $6\times 6$ matrices of the following form:
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
                  A  & B \\
                   C & D
\end{pmatrix}  \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
                  ?  & \Phi(B) \\
                   \Phi(C^T)^T & ?
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
?

The question marks denote two linear operators which may depend on $A,B,C$ and $D.$

I know that the transposition would a counterexample if we work with a positive extension
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
                  \Phi_1(A)  & \Phi(B) \\
                   \Phi(C^T)^T & \Phi_2(D)
\end{pmatrix};
\end{align*} i.e. the transposition is not a complete contraction.
But what about if we allow much more general extensions like
\begin{align*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
                  \Phi_1(A,B,C,D)  & \Phi(B) \\
                   \Phi(C^T)^T & \Phi_2(A,B,C,D) 
\end{pmatrix}?
\end{align*}
Now the transposition fits into the setting by choosing $\Phi_1(A,B,C,D) = D$ and $\Phi_2(A,B,C,D) = A$ because

\begin{align*}
 \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & I \\
                    I & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
                    A & B \\
                   B^T & D 
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & I \\
                    I & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
       =  \begin{pmatrix}
                    D & B^T \\
                    B & A 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
are positive.